# Install nvidia drivers for Ubuntu 18.04 SERVER

Tags: server, 18.04, nvidia

I need to install the nvidia drivers for Ubuntu SERVER 18.04.2, to run computations from a headless server on a nvidia RTX card.

I am asking because I have not yet found any clear guide to do that for the server 18.04.2 version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run the following commands in your terminal to install the latest NVIDIA Drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If you get any unmet dependencies problems, manually install those unmet dependencies. For example, if you get:

```
nvidia-driver-418 : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418  (418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Run:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 nvidia-driver-418
```

Finally, reboot.

Comment: This was very help for me and ended up resolving a transcoding problem I was experiencing on my Plex server running Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS. Thank you for the helping the community with this easy to follow post.