# Surface Pro 18.04 dosn't suspend to memory

Tags: 18.04, suspend, surface

Somehow I can't manage so suspend my Surface. I tried this steps in [monty47's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close/1036122#1036122) to [Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close):

```
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle]
```

Any attempt to write that file with sudo throws an error.

I updated GRUB:

```
cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

But still it won't suspend to mem. `journalctl` shows:

```
Dez 14 13:03:31 msf kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Dez 14 13:03:33 msf kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to

#### activate suspend

by changing the display manager to lightdm by running:

`sudo apt install lightdm`

and choosing lightdm or if lightdm is already installed

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

and choosing lightdm

#### To activate hibernation

Enable resume

1. find UUID of swap partition

`sudo blkid | grep swap`

2. open a new file

`sudo -H gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

and add

`RESUME=UUID=<<UUID of swap partition>>`

edited /etc/default/grub

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

and added the UUID to the line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=<UUID of swap partition>"`

example

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=4b1c58e1-5bc5-4bce-a64e-e195cb38d01f"`

3. Enable hibernate entry in main menu:

Run

`sudo -H gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

copy paste the following contents:

````
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate to be run via cron]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes```
````

To disable Hibernate: change yes to no in the last lines of each entry.

#### Finally

````
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u```
````

and ***reboot***

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help

Comment: If you have Nvidia graphics try updating from repository [like here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130895/install-nvidia-drivers-for-ubuntu-18-04-server)